# Interface and data member of a derived class

Tags: c++

Let B be the base class, and D the derived class. If B has 3 private data members in its interface, and D has 2 private data members. How many data members does a D object actually have?

Comment: Show the code. Private members are not interface in the language of my tribe.

Comment: What does it mean "have a data member"? Every field occupies memory regardless if it is public or private. So you just sum up the numbers. However, if you mean members that are visible for the user of your object, then, well... there are none, as everything is private.

Answer (score 0):

For me it will have 2 fields, because private encapsulation means these fields can only be accessed within the class they are declared in.